# How can I get the value of variables that have a specific pattern?

Tags: shell-script

```
read -p "Please enter the number of loops:" num

for((i=1;i<=$num;i++))
do
  read -p "Please enter number $i:" number$i
done
```

I want to get the value of variable sets with a specific pattern "number".

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using `bash`:

```
read -p 'Please enter the number of iterations: ' niter

for (( i = 0; i < niter; ++i )); do
    read -p "Please enter number $(( i + 1 )): " num[i]
done

echo 'All numbers:'
printf '\t%s\n' "${num[@]}"
```

That is, use an array.

Running it:

```
$ bash script.sh
Please enter the number of iterations: 3
Please enter number 1: 12
Please enter number 2: 21
Please enter number 3: tom
All numbers:
        12
        21
        tom
```

The next issue you'll have is to verify that the user enters numbers.